# Question about compact sets and coverings

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $K \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be sequentially compact. Then for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $x_1,...,x_m \in K $ such that $K \subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^n B(x_i, \epsilon ) $.

Proof

Suppose by contradiction the conclusion is false and fix $\epsilon > 0$. We build a sequence as follows:

Pick $x_1 \in K$ such that $K \nsubseteq B(x_1,\epsilon) $

Pick $x_2 \in K \setminus B(x_1, \epsilon) $ such that $K \nsubseteq B(x_1,\epsilon) \cup B(x_2, \epsilon) $

Continuing in this fashion, suppose $x_1,...,x_m \in K $ have been selected so that for all $i \leq m$, $x_i \in K \setminus \bigcup_{j=1}^{m-1} B(x_j, \epsilon) $ so that

$$ K \nsubseteq \bigcup_{j=1}^m B(x_j, \epsilon) $$

So, picking $x_{m+1} \in \bigcup_{j=1}^m B(x_j, \epsilon)$

we obtain a sequence $(x_n)$ in $K$. By construction, we see $(x_n)$ cannot be cauchy. Using compactness, there exists a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ of $(x_n)$ that converges to an element $L \in K$. My question: How does this contradict my hypothesis?

Is it because

since $(x_n)$ is not cauchy, then $(x_n)$ is not convergent?

I remember from calculus we can have a sequence that is not convergent but can have a convergent subsequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The crux is that not only is this sequence not Cauchy, but no subsequence of it can be Cauchy, because $d(x_i,x_j) \geq \varepsilon$ for all $i \neq j$.  But since $K$ is compact *some* subsequence must be convergent (and therefore Cauchy).

---

Incidentally, if your assumption is that $\varepsilon > 0$ is such that there are not finitely many $x_1 , \ldots , x_m \in K$ such that $K \subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^m B(x_i,\varepsilon)$, then in your induction step you just need to pick any $x_{m+1} \in K \setminus \bigcup_{i=1}^m B(x_i,\varepsilon)$ (since $x_1 , \ldots , x_m , x_{m+1}$ will continue to share the desired property by assumption).

Comment: Thanks Arthur for your answer, but I dont understand why no subsequence of my sequence cannot be cauchy. Can you explain a little bit more this part? thanks a lot

Comment: @ThomasMann: Recall that Cauchy means that for all $\delta > 0$ there is an $n$ such that $d(x_i,x_j) < \delta$ for all $i,j \geq n$. If $\langle x_{i_j} \rangle_{j}$ is any subsequence of the sequence constructed, note that $d(x_{i_j} , x_{i_{j+1}} ) \geq \varepsilon$ for all $j$. From this it follows that there cannot be a desired $n$ for $\delta = \varepsilon$ (given any $n$ consider $i=n$ and $j = n+1$).

Comment: clear now. Thank you very much sir. One last question: I find this kind of proofs kind of hard, but I get it now. Is it ok to find it difficult at first? Or, is this something very easy, and i should not have problems with it?

Comment: @ThomasMann: It's always okay if you have to struggle: eventually everyone does! The only advise I can give is to ensure that you fully digest the proofs you come across, even if you have to spend a seemingly long time doing so; it's much more important to go through a proof well than to go through it quickly. That process of digestion should make it easier when you come across a similar proof, make the connections between the concepts a little more concrete, and give you an idea of the "rules of the game" when you have to produce proofs of your own.